# Embedding Facebook photo albums with like button, on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-comments

Can I do something like this?

I want to have all the photos from my fan page, embedded on my website.
Want to have the option to like each photo - must.
Want that each photo will have a link to the real URL on Facebook - must.
Would like to share and comment as well but not as important.

Please let me know if you have an idea of how I can do it. 
I saw a lot of examples but nothing that include these things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting some of the photos is easy. Getting all of the photos is nearly impossible. Start with a [Graph API call to the photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object.

To get the photos, create and app, install the PHP SDK on your site. This code should get you started.

```
$config = array(
   'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
   'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
);
 if (!class_exists('Facebook')) 
    include_once 'PATH_TO_SDK/facebook.php';
 $fb_object = new Facebook($config);

 $photos = $fb_object->api('PAGE_ID_OR_USERNAME/photos', 'GET');
 printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($photos, true));
```

You'll need to iterate through these results to get more than 15 of your photos. Photos that aren't marked as "Public" won't be returned by this API call.

To create a like or a comment, you need to auth the user and then POST to the Graph API using the photo id.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorial for that? Anyone know how to pass the limit of 15 images? Can you give further info about adding the like and comment if you know..? Thanks!